# Can someone please help me reverse engineer this assembly code to C please!

Tags: disassembly, assembly, c

I am really bad at understanding assembly code and the way it works. I have little problems given to me in Assembly code and I have to reverse engineer it to C, but I have been doing really bad job at it so far. Can someone tell me what this code translates to in C.

```
    .file   "hw4.c"
    .text
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  p1
    .type   p1, @function

.LFB14:
    .cfi_startproc
    movl    (%rdi), %eax
    addl    (%rsi), %eax
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE14:
    .size   p1, .-p1
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  p2
    .type   p2, @function
```

Comment: Welcome to RE.SE. Is this your homework? Translating asm to pseudo C is not actually reverse engineering. Start by reading on the directives in your code, flags, registers and instructions. You can't offload your homework to SE unless you show some research done/understanding.

Answer (score 1):

It is just a function that perform a simple addition:

```
int add(int *i, int *j)
{
  return *i + *j;
}
```

Comment: `rdi` and `rsi` are addresses to the actual numbers being added.

Comment: RIght. I fixed this on the code,my bad.